# How do you select what properties will be displayed when databinding to a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

Binding a List collection to a datagrid.  How can you limit what properties will be displayed?

```
DataGridViewAirport.DataSource = GlobalDisplayAirports
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off AutoGenerateColumns, and then you can explicitly create the columns you need. For example here's an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0">
    <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:C}"/>

    </Columns>
```

Another option would to be hide the columns after you data bind, but this above is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks Josh, sorry should have been more specific, I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: Ok solution is still the same, just my sample is off.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your dataSource you could mark the properties you don't want to show then you can leave autogenerate columns on.

I believe this is correct VB:

```
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)> _
```

in C# it is

```
[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
```

Another Useful attribute is

```
[DisplayName("Total Amount")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have set a motif on all of our classes to create a method called TailorDGV that we pass a reference to the datagrid into the method that it then returns.

This method then loops through and hides all columns. Then it turns on the columns required and either sets a fixed width or sets the system to autosize to fill the grid with the columns that are visible.

```
        With dgvControl
            For i As Integer = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                .Columns(i).Visible = False
            Next
        End With
```

You can also set the location of a column in the grid using the DisplayIndex property on the column object of the grid. This property is zero based.